# NoSuchMethodFound exception

Tags: java

I keep getting this error message:

```
06-13 18:53:33.839: W/System.err(19893): java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: showIt
06-13 18:53:33.839: W/System.err(19893):    at java.lang.ClassCache.findMethodByName(ClassCache.java:247)
06-13 18:53:33.839: W/System.err(19893):    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:731)
```

I'm sure my method exists, I try to start from within a asynctask.
This is the method:

```
public static void showIt(String[] result) {
```

And this is the code I've tried:

```
try {
            Class<?> p = Class.forName(executeClass);
            Object t = p.newInstance();

            Method m = p.getDeclaredMethod(executeMethod, p);
            m.invoke(t, result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three problems ...

- getDeclaredMethod second argument must be an array of parameters classes of the showIt method.
- Because the method is static, it is useless to pass an object to the first argument of invoke method.
- Because the invoke method is varargs, result must be wrapped into a Object[] in order to be passed as excepted.

Finally, here is a working code snipet.

```
String[] result = new String[] { "res" };
Class<?> p = Class.forName(executeClass);

Method m = p.getDeclaredMethod("showIt", result.getClass());
m.invoke(null, new Object[] {result});
```

Comment: Good point Toilal, I was missing problem 3 in my answer. Anyway, I don't understand: why a vararg argument need to be wrapped in array? Don't this make vararg useless

Comment: It's really strange, because varargs works as expected on other methods... just tryed           

    public static void showIt(Long... result) {
        System.out.println(result[0].toString());
    }

and i callable with showIt(12l) as expected;

Answer (score 1):

Given `executeClass = "YourClass"` and `executeMethod = "showIt"`, `p.getDeclaredMethod(executeMethod, p)` is trying to find `showIt(YourClass arg)`, but you have `showIt(String[] arg)`.

Try `p.getDeclaredMethod(executeMethod, String[].class)`.

Answer (score 0):

You got two mistakes here:

1. you have to pass getDeclaredMethod the type of argument as second parameter, and not the type of your class (p)
2. since your method is static, you have to pass null as first parameter to invoke, and you don't need to create the t instance.

.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){


        try {
            Class<?> p = Main.class;

            String[] arguments = {"ciao"};
            Method m = p.getDeclaredMethod("showIt",String[].class);

            m.invoke(null, arguments);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void showIt(String[] result) {
        System.out.println(result[0]);
    }
}
```