# Why reflection invoke method require varargs to be wrapped in array?

Tags: java

Answering [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092844/nosuchmethodfound-exception) on S.O. , I got this strange problem that I cannot understand. Why reflection 'invoke' method of Method class require varargs argument to be wrapped in an array in order to work?

Other classes methods with vararg arguments runs fine just calling them the normal way...

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args){


    try {
        Class<?> p = Main.class;

        String[] arguments1 = {"ciao"};
        String[] arguments2 = {"salve"};
        String[] arguments3 = {"buonasera"};

        Method m = p.getDeclaredMethod("showIt",String[].class);


        //this is ok
        showIt(arguments1);

        //this is ok
        m.invoke(null, new Object[]{arguments2});

        //this throws IllegalArgumentException!!
        m.invoke(null, arguments3);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void showIt(String[] result) {
    System.out.println(result[0]);
  }


}
```

What is special in invoke method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets say that we have method

```
public static void someMethod(String... arguments){
    // implementation is irrelevant but will add it for demo purpose
    System.out.println("I have "+arguments.length +"arguments which are:");
    for (String arg:arguments)
        System.out.println(arg);
}
```

You probably know that vararg is in fact array but it is special since it allows arguments to be passed in form

- `someMethod("arg1")`
- `someMethod("arg1", "arg2")`.

But lets not forget that since `...` is array accept array argument like

- `someMethod(new MyArgumentsType[]{arg1, arg2, arg3})`.

---

We know that `invoke` is declared as `public Object invoke(Object obj, Object... args)`

Now you want to invoke method `showIt(String[] result)` that require `String[]` as argument.

You call `invoke` method this way `m.invoke(null, arguments3);`. Since every array can be treated as `Object[]` `invoke` will understand that you are passing set of arguments in array (take a look at 3rd way of invoking `someMethod` in my example). This way method will find only one argument: `"buonasera"`. But `showIt` requires `String[]` not `String` so you will see "*argument type mismatch"* exception.

To get rid of this problem you have two options.

1. Wrap your String array in some other array like you are doing in `m.invoke(null, new Object[] { arguments2 });`. This way varargs will treat contend of that Object array as list of arguments, so it will find wrapped String[] array as argument which is correct.
2. Cast your array to Object, to show that array is just one argument, not set of arguments
   and should be treated as in case 1. and 2. in my `someMethod` example

   ```
   m.invoke(null, (Object) arguments3);
   ```

Comment: Thank you @Pshemo, I perfectly understand your explanation, and, infact, by casting the array to object it's working perfectly

Answer (score 7):

This is because there is an ambiguity here with respect to varargs and array arguments types. Basically, when a method is declared as

```
void takesSomeArgs(Object... values) {
}
```

this is mostly equivalent to

```
void takesSomeArgs(Object[] values) {
}
```

The problem is, that there are now two potential (and equally valid) interpretations of the following call:

```
Object[] example = { "foo", "bar" };
takesSomeArgs(example);
```

The first interpretation would be

- call the method with a single argument value, i.e., `values` being something like `Object[1] { Object[1] { "foo", "bar" } }` (varargs interpretation)
- call the method with two argument values, i.e., `values` being something like `Object[2] { "foo", "bar" }`, since `Object...` is essentially `Object[]`, and thus, we can pass the array reference from `example` directly as the value of `value`.

Under the rules from the [JLS 15.12.2.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.3), the compiler subscribes to the second interpretation (on the invocation of `invoke(Object, Object...)` itself, which is variadic), which results in an attempt to pass *two* arguments to your method -- which fails, since the method expects only one (**EDIT** Note, that I am describing the wrong symptom here; see Json's answer, which gets it right). In other words, a call like:

```
m.invoke(receiver, new Object[] { "a", "b", "c" });
```

and

```
m.invoke(receiver, "a", "b", "c");
```

are effectively the very same thing. And hence the need to write

```
m.invoke(receiver, new Object[] { new Object[] { "a", "b", "c" } });  // (X)
```

(explicitly) or

```
m.invoke(receiver, (Object) (new Object[] { "a", "b", "c" }));
```

Note the cast: it makes the argument no longer convertible to `Object[]` and forces the compiler to generate the code equivalent to (X). Also note, that the `new Object[] { ... }` are not to be taken literally, but are only intended to make the types of the values involved clear.

It seems to me, that this is an unfortunate side-effect of the fact, that the designers of the Java language wanted to make it possible (and convenient) to implement something like

```
void logError(String control, Object... parameters) {
    // Forwarding the unknown number of arguments from one variadic method
    // to the next: String.format(String, Object...)
    log.message(String.format(control, parameters));  
}
```

without introducing new syntax.

Comment: Uhm, ok I think I get it, but why this apply only to invoke? If I change showIt signaure to be showIt(Object... result) I can call it showIt("ciao") and it just work. I expect the same ambiguity apply to my methods. Instead, both showIt(new String[]{"ciao"}) and showIt("ciao") works and print "ciao"

Comment: @AndreaParodi: See my additions. Also, have a look at the "work-around" via cast to `Object`, so that the array value is no longer eligible for being passed "as is".

Comment: It's because the `...` is just syntactic sugar - it's equivalent to providing an array of objects.  Hence why you can't define two methods `foo(Object...)` and `foo(Object[])` - to the compiler, they both create a method that takes an array of objects.  Reflection has no idea that you've declared the method using the alternative syntax.

Comment: @RobI: Yes, that's why I wrote, that both forms are "mostly equivalent". Both declarations generate the same method signature, and the only difference is, how the compiler may compile calls to methods declared with `Object[]` vs `Object...`.

Comment: Thank for your efforts, Dirk. I've understood the concept. I think @Pshemo response is simpler more direct, but I wish I could accept two answer for one question...

Answer (score 3):

There *are* two interpretations of

```
m.invoke(null, arguments3);
```

The first interpretation is equivalent to

```
m.invoke(null, (Object)arguments3);
```

The second interpretation is equivalent to

```
m.invoke(null, (Object[])arguments3);
```

Note that this is different than

```
m.invoke(null, new Object[] { arguments3 });
```

This is very important. In the second interpretation, `String[]` is itself being cast to an `Object[]` and used at the `args` parameter to `invoke`; that is `arguments3` is being treated as `args`, *not* as an element of the array that makes up `args`.

Java will pick the second interpretation by default. In that case, it will then unwrap the elements of the `Object[]` and use those as the parameters to `showIt`. So from the perspective of `showIt`, it looks like it is being invoked as

```
showIt("buonasera")
```

and that's clearly not valid because `showIt` is expecting a `String[]`, not a `String`.

In fact, if you read the documentation for [Method.invoke](http://bit.ly/x87P8I) you'll see:

> `IllegalArgumentException` - if the method is an instance method and the specified object argument is not an instance of the class or interface declaring the underlying method (or of a subclass or implementor thereof); if the number of actual and formal parameters differ; if an unwrapping conversion for primitive arguments fails; **or if, after possible unwrapping, a parameter value cannot be converted to the corresponding formal parameter type by a method invocation conversion.**

and that is exactly what is happening here. Again, because it looks like `showIt` is being invoked with a single `String` parameter, not a single `String[]` parameter.

But in the first interpretation, we are treating `String[]` as an instance of `Object` and using that as the single element in an `Object[]` in the varargs `args` parameter. So, if you explicitly tell Java it can't do that implicit cast of `String[]` to `Object[]`, then the `String[]` will end up being passed as the first formal parameter, instead of using the elements of the `String[]` as the formal parameters to `showIt`.

Thus,

```
m.invoke(null, (Object)arguments3);
```

will work just fine.

Comment: Yeah... You are right. Though I stand by my explanation, I did describe the wrong symptom. Will fix the answer. Note, btw., that the `new Object[] { ... }` was not intended to be taken literally. All I wanted to achieve there was to make the type (and array-ness-or-not) of the values clear.

Answer (score -1):

If you have two overloaded methods:

```
showIt(String firstname, String lastname);

showIt(String names ...);
```

When you call `invoke`, java must know which method you are calling. Pass two parameters call the first one, Pass a string array call the second one.